# Extension of Schengen Visa due to marriage with a German citizen

Tags: schengen

I am a Philippine passport holder and hold a Schengen Short Stay Visa with duration of 13 days. I intend to get married to a German citizen. Is it possible to apply for extension of duration of stay to maximum possible 90 days (or beyond that)? How can this be done legally while waiting for the processing of marriage documents which will surely take time?

Comment: You can try asking at the local Ausländerbehörde, but I doubt they'll do it.  If you get married within the 13 day stay, you may be able to apply to stay as the spouse of a German citizen, but getting the paperwork done that quickly seems unlikely.  You should also know that after you marry you will fall under the EU freedom of movement when traveling with (or to join) your spouse.  This means that you can stay in *other* EU and Schengen countries very easily, but it doesn't apply to you in Germany unless your spouse has exercised freedom-of-movement rights in another country.

Answer (score 1):

To marry your German fiancé(e), you should follow the procedure outlined in this document from the German Embassy in Manila.  It appears that you cannot make this application while you are in Germany:

http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618538/Daten/7244286/MB_marriage.pdf

In particular, note:

> The sponsor must visit the local Registry Office to register the marriage BEFORE the visa application is submitted at the
>   Embassy. The Philippine fiancé(e) does not have to travel to Germany for this.
>
> The visa application must be immediately rejected if it is submitted without this proof of registration

You can get more general information about the process on the [appropriate webpage of the diplomatic service](http://www.manila.diplo.de/Vertretung/manila/en/05/1_20Visabestimmungen/Visaprocedure__and__forms.html).  There is a *Marriage Visa* section with the following links:

> - [Application requirements for a visa for marriage an subsequent permanent stay in Germany [pdf, 400.87k]](http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618538/Daten/7244286/MB_marriage.pdf)
> - [Application form [pdf, 621.91k]](http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618414/Daten/4777782/ddatei_application_long_stay.pdf)
> - [Appointment system [pdf, 259.4k]](http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618532/Daten/6736302/MB_visa_appointment.pdf)
> - [Online appointment system](https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/choose_realmList.do?request_locale=en&locationCode=mani)
> - [Information provided to applicants pursuant to Section 54 Residence Act [pdf, 327.96k]](http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618434/Daten/6179269/ddatei_security_decl_jan16.pdf)
> - [Visa photo](http://www.manila.diplo.de/Vertretung/manila/en/05/1_20Visabestimmungen/Visa_20photo.html)

You may also be interested in these blog posts outlining the procedure, from [Pinays in Germany](https://pinayingermany.wordpress.com):

- [Marriage / Fiance Visa: Getting Married in Germany](https://pinayingermany.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/marriage-fiance-visa-getting-married-in-germany/)
- [Getting Married in Germany: Marriage Visa](https://pinayingermany.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/getting-married-in-germany-marriage-visa/)