# Marriage with Schengen visa in Germany with German citizen

Tags: visa, germany, marriage, schengen

I would like to know if it's possible for my boyfriend to come to marry me in Germany with a Schengen visa.  He holds an Azerbaijani passport.
It would be very helpful because right now I am pregnant and would like to get married as soon as possible.

I'm German and my boyfriend didn't make his visa yet but going to do it next week. I can't wait 3 month for him to reach Germany that why I'm thinking Schengen Visa is the fastest visa that he could give and me as a German I think maybe I can help him to get the visa to live with me in Germany

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/10628/14680 ?

Comment: In particular, note the link to this [document](http://www.manila.diplo.de/contentblob/3618538/Daten/7244286/MB_marriage.pdf) from the German embassy in Manilla.  There may be a similar document from the embassy in Azerbaijan.

Comment: Final comment: Providing the baby is his, this is *supposed* to be possible - you all three have a right to a family life together.

Comment: http://www.baku.diplo.de/contentblob/1774182/Daten/8096942/M_D_Ehegattennachzug.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Go straight to the nearest Standesamt and ask them about the exact steps you need to do. You can't just get married - you need to fulfil all the German requirements to make the marriage legal, and also all the Azerbeijan legal requirements. You won't be able to do this in a few days; you will need all the right papers, you will need official translations, there may be things that need to be done in Azerbeijan (but may be done in a consulate in Germany).

Now the part you don't want to hear: There are plenty of people out there who want you as a means to provide a visa and nothing else. Of course that's not happening in your place, but don't provide loans, hand over your savings, be a loan guarantor and so on.

Comment: Are u telling me cuz u know about German or you are German citizen?

Comment: I know they are steps that I need to follow and paper that need to be translate it's not only in Germany it's everywhere.